# Create a Runnable Jar for data driven project having customized excel for input data

Tags: java, maven, selenium

I have created a maven selenium project with data driven approach(reading input from excel files). I want to create a runnable jar file and setup the jar file to 3rd party client system who should be able to execute the jar by changing the input from excel file as per the his requirement.

Comment: Are you using any framework like JUnit or TestNg? To have a runnable jar file your tests should run from a main method (`public static void main(String[] args)`)

Answer (score 0):

Call your testclass from a main class.
Use TestNG or JUNIT.
I guess you use the Apache.POI.
you have to set a relative filepath to your excel-file with the testdata, so if you build a .jar you can place the file next to it.

a call from main-method with JUNIT can be:

```
public static void main Testsuite(final String args[]){
JUnitCore.main(Testclass.class.getCanonicalName());
    }
```

With TestNG the whole thing is a bit more text i guess. I used it two years ago. Now i use JUNIT 4 again.